# PowerBI - can't use a calculated column in measures

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

(I'm very new to PowerBI)

I'm facing an issue for using a the data of a calculated column in PowerBI.

So first, what I'm trying to get is a boolean or a fixed value from the comparison of 2 values (number of seconds).
So it would be something like this :

```
(Duration * 0.3) + AvgDuration < Duration then True else False
```

The Duration data is stored in a calculated column build this way :

[image]

and the calcul is :

```
= Table.AddColumn(EXECUTIONS_Table, "Duration", each [DT_END] - [DT_START], type duration)
```

As for the AvgDuration data comes from a referenced table (the same table where the Duration column is) and the definition of the column is :

[image]

```
= Table.Group(#"Filtered Rows", {"ID_OBJECT"}, {{"AvgDuration", each List.Average([Duration]), type number}})
```

So I'm trying to create a measure (or other) that returns a boolean from these two columns but from what I tried the Duration calculated columns can only be used through aggregate functions and I struggle achieving that.
So is there a better solution to it, like not using a measure or rethink the calculated columns, ...

Thanks